# How do Javascript objects work?

Tags: javascript

### Preface

1. I know the right code for these examples.
2. What I want to know is *why* the following examples won't work as expected.

### Code

- With parentheses when calling `sayIt` function.

  ```
  function Fruit(type){
      this.type = type;
      this.taste = "Awful";
      this.thought = sayIt();
  }

  function sayIt(){
      return this.taste+" "+ this.type;
  }

  window.onload = function (){
      var lemon= new Fruit("Lemon");
      alert(lemon.thought);
  };
  ```

  This will alert "undefined undefined", why?
- `sayIt` function without parentheses.

  ```
  function Fruit (type){
      this.type = type;
      this.taste = "Awful";
      this.thought = sayIt;
  }

  function sayIt(){
      return this.taste +" "+ this.type;
  }

  window.onload = function (){
      var lemon= new Fruit("Lemon");
      alert(lemon.thought);
  };
  ```

  This will literally write down the function on the alert box, why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will you accept the answer: `because`

Comment: SO supports markdown: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help No need for HTML.

Comment: these don't work as expected because what you're expecting is not accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Notes inline, discussion below, references and further reading at the end:**

- With parentheses when calling `sayIt` function.

  ```
  function Fruit(type){
      this.type = type;
      this.taste = "Awful";
      // Here, you're *calling* the `sayIt` function and assigning its
      // return value to `this.thought`. During the call, `this` will
      // refer to the global object (not to the `Fruit` instance).
      this.thought = sayIt();
  }

  function sayIt(){
      // If this is called as it is above, `this` is the global object,
      // which is `window` in browsers. Since `window` doesn't have
      // `taste` or `type` properties, this returns "undefined undefined".
      // That's what `this.thought` above receives.
      return this.taste+" "+ this.type;
  }

  window.onload = function (){
      var lemon= new Fruit("Lemon");
      // You've said this alerts "undefined undefined", but I think you'll
      // find it just alerts "undefined" (singular). There is no `sayIt`
      // property on the `lemon` instance at all. If you alerted
      // `lemon.thought` instead, you'd see the "undefined undefined" we
      // stored there above.
      alert(lemon.sayIt);
  };
  ```
- `sayIt` function without parentheses.

  ```
  function Fruit (type){
      this.type = type;
      this.taste = "Awful";
      // Here you're assigning the `sayIt` function to `this.thought`.
      // Perfectly normal stuff.
      this.thought = sayIt;
  }

  function sayIt(){
      return this.taste +" "+ this.type;
  }

  window.onload = function (){
      var lemon= new Fruit("Lemon");
      // Here you're also *referring* to the function object, not calling
      // it. (To call a function, you use `()` after it.) So since functions
      // are objects, you're passing an object reference into `alert`.
      // Alert will try to convert that to a string, and the
      // implementation of `toString` on `Function` objects in most
      // environments is to dump out a version of the source code of
      // the function (although this behavior is *not* standardized and
      // some browsers, esp. mobile browsers, don't do it).
      alert(lemon.thought);
  };
  ```

Key concepts from the above:

1. Functions are objects. You *call* a function by using a reference to it followed by `()`, e.g.:

   ```
   x = foo();
   ```

   means "call `foo` and assign its return value to `x`".

   You *refer* to the function object by just using its name, *sans* `()`, e.g.:

   ```
   x = foo;
   ```

   means "assign the function object `foo` to `x`. (You could then call it: `x()`.)
2. Unlike some other languages, in JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not *where it's defined*. When you call a function via a free variable (e.g., `foo()`), you're doing nothing to explicitly set the `this` for the function call, and so `this` will be the default value, which is the global object (`window` on browsers).

   You can set what `this` is in two different ways:

   A. Put the function reference on an object property and call the function via the property's reference to it, e.g.:

   ```
   // To put it on whatever `this` is at the moment:
   this.thought = sayIt;

   // Or to put it on an object we have in the variable `x`:

   x.thought = sayIt;
   ```

   You'd then call it via the property:

   ```
   this.thought();
   x.thought();
   ```

   Within the function call, `this` will refer to the object from which you retrieved the property.

   B. Using the function object's intrinsic `call` or `apply` functions:

   ```
   sayIt.call(lemon);
   ```

   means "call the `sayIt` function, making `this` = `lemon` within the function call." If you pass further arguments to `call`, they'll be passed to the function, so:

   ```
   sayIt.call(lemon, 1, 2, 3);
   ```

   means "call `sayIt` with `this` = `lemon` and pass in `1`, `2`, and `3`.

   There's also the `apply` function, which is just the same thing except you pass the arguments as an array rather than individually:

   ```
   // note ------------v-------v---- the square brackets create an array
   sayIt.applyl(lemon, [1, 2, 3]);

   // More explicitly:
   var a = [1, 2, 3];
   sayIt.apply(lemon, a);
   ```

   means "call `sayIt` with `this` = `lemon` and pass in `1`, `2`, and `3`.

I've blogged a bit on these subjects, FWIW:

- [Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [Anonymouses anonymous](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) (talks more about function references and assigning them)

More to explore:

- [The ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (yes, really)
- [MDC's JavaScript pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)
- [Crockford's JavaScript pages](http://javascript.crockford.com/) (advanced, read and understand **all** of the above first)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming there is a typo in the first example and you meant to write `alert(lemon.thought())`. The reason you're seeing `undefined undefined` is because `this.thought` is set to the return value of the `sayIt` function. In the `sayIt` function, `this` refers to the `window` object and not the `Fruit` object. Since `window` doesn't have a `taste` or `type` property, you will see `undefined undefined`.

In the second example (I'll again assume you have a typo and you meant to do `alert(lemon.thought())`), you `this.thought` is set to be a reference to the `sayIt` function, so you're not actually calling it. When you alert a reference to a function, it will print out the source of that function.

**BONUS**

You can get it to work the way you want if you do this:

```
this.thought = sayIt.call(this);
```

This will set the `this` to point to the `Fruit` object and now `sayIt` will return what you want.

In the second example, you will get what you want if you do this:

```
alert(lemon.thought());
```

`lemon.thought` refers to `sayIt` and the `this` will be set properly because you are calling a member function of `lemon`.

The first argument to `call` (or its friend `apply`) is for the value of `this` in the context of that function.

**UPDATE**

Dan, in the second example even without the change I made, that is if you still have `lemon.thought = sayIt;` and you say `alert(lemon.thought);`. You will still get the source of the function because you're not calling the function and passing its result to `alert`. You're passing the function reference itself to `alert`, and so it will print the source.

Comment: +1  If I had a complete understanding of the rules for where "this" points to at any given point I could die a happy man.

Comment: @kekekela `this` is tricky in Javascript :). You can set it explicitly when you use either `apply` or `call`.

Comment: Uppss.. yes it is a typo, it should be `alert(lemon.thought);`

Comment: In the second example, `alert(lemon.thought());` is much easier. Don't make it more complicated than it is ;)

Comment: @Vivin Paliath: No, the 2nd example was meant to be like that, so that was why I ask.

Comment: @Felix Ah yes if he was using the first example. But if `this.thought` is only set to `sayIt`, calling `lemon.thought()` will still return `undefined undefined`. So that's why you have to do `lemon.thought(lemon)`.

Comment: @Vivin: I don't know if I understand. If `this.thought` is a reference to `sayIt`, then when calling `lemon.though()`, `this` inside the function will refer to `lemon`.

Comment: @Felix You're correct! :) I was mixing up the two. My bad! I've fixed it.

Comment: @Vivin: *"`this` is tricky in Javascript :)"* `this` is very *simple* in JavaScript. I think there are two rules. So simple, it trips people up, I think because they expect it (reasonably, but incorrectly) to even vaguely resemble `this` in nearly any other language. ;-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I hope I don't sound too cocky when I say I understand how `this` works. But I said that because when I was first learning Javascript `this` baffled me and when I eventually understood it, it was simple. So I was making that statement from my own personal experience. I should have phrased it like you did: "seems tricky, but is quite simple!". :)

Comment: @Vivin: Like so much of the language. :-)

Comment: @T. J. Crowder completely agree. Most people get frustrated by Javascript because they expect it to work like a traditional OO model (a la Java/C++/C#).

Answer (score 2):

First code:

**EDIT** NB: edited to reflect edits in the question

```
function Fruit(type){
    this.type = type;
    this.taste = "Awful";
    this.thought = sayIt(); // this line invokes sayIt, with global context,
                            // so sets thought to 'undefined undefined'
}

function sayIt() {
    return this.taste+" "+ this.type; // as called, this == window, not the Fruit object
}

window.onload = function() {
    var lemon= new Fruit("Lemon");
    alert(lemon.thought);    // see above
};
```

Second code:

```
function Fruit (type){
    this.type = type;
    this.taste = "Awful";
    this.thought = sayIt;
}

function sayIt(){
    return this.taste +" "+ this.type;
}

window.onload = function (){
    var lemon= new Fruit("Lemon");
    alert(lemon.thought);  // doesn't -call- the function, results in .toString() on
                           // the function object
};
```

Comment: +1 "// as called, this == window" I wish I could get my head around how you guys know this, I'm always terrified to use 'this' because I'm worried its going to be pointing to "not what I think it is".

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a mistake in the first example. You wrote `alert(lemon.sayIt);` where it should be `alert(lemon.thought);`. Anyway...

> With parentheses when calling `sayIt` function. This will alert "undefined undefined", why?

Because when you execute `this.thought = sayIt();`, you are assigning the **return value** of `sayIt` to `this.thought`. When you call `sayIt()`, then `this` inside the function will refer to the global object which is `window` is browser. And `window.taste` and `window.type` are not defined. Hence `this.thought` will have string `"undefined undefined"` assigned to it.

> `sayIt` function without parentheses. This will literally write down the function on the alert box, why?

In this case you are assigning a reference to the function itself to `this.tought`. The string representation of a function is the code itself. Now you can call the function via `lemon.tought()`. If you do so, `this` will refer to the `lemon` object and the output will be as expected.

So, call the function: `alert(lemon.tought())`.

I suggest you read about

- [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)
- [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the "lemon" object has the properties "type", "taste", and "thought".

```
alert(lemon.sayIt);
```

This line alerts the value of the "sayIt" property on "lemon", converted to a String. Since the "lemon" object doesn't have a "sayIt" property, it converts the value *undefined* to a string and displays it.

```
alert(lemon.thought);
```

This line alerts the value of the "thought" property on "lemon", converted to a String. Since the "thought" property is a function, the string conversion displays the text of the function.

What you probably want to do is call the function, and display its return value:
    alert(lemon.thought());

Answer (score 0):

1. The function sayIt is defined after it is called.  Moving the definition of sayIt above the definition of fruit would fix.
2. You're alerting the definition of a function and not the return value from calling that function.

Answer (score 0):

sayIt is not a function of the Fruit object - it's a function of the window object.

Fruit.thought is a function, or a "function pointer" as it is assigned to the window.sayIt function.